# The file “AppName.build” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: ios, xcode, permissions

```
error: could not read data from '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-fqotffhinyvhgldyfjeewjtygdpe/Build/Intermediates/AppName.build/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.build/': The file “AppName.build” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
```

This actually happening when in console I see "Prosess Info.plist ...". But I don't really think that Info.plist is causing error.
What I did or checked:

1. "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" is Default Compiler
2. Window - Projects - The app with the issue - delete button in
   Derived Data
3. Architectures are perfect and the same in Architectures and Valid
           Architectures
4. Update to recommended settings, clean project and
       clean build folder infinite times.
5. Check Info.plist property in
       "Packaging". Checked fields:  Bundle name As : ${PRODUCT_NAME}
       Executable file : ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}  Replace info.plist with new
       from the project with the same name.
6. I just composed new project and
       copy all files and resourses to the new project. But even this
       didn't help.

   Please, help! I'm thinking about suicide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actully after long research I noticed eventually that one of last created xib files have the space before it's name (that I by chance leaved, when created file). After deleting that project was built.
Apple, why!??